# Remove adjacent duplicates on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Suppose we have an array of numbers like the next one:

```
const input = [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];
```

The goal is to remove duplicates values, but only if they are adjacent. So, the expected output for the previous sample should be:

```
[2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

So far, I managed to almost solve this using a recursive approach, but for some reason that I can't figure, the generated result is not returned (however, you can see it on the log before the returning condition).

```js
const input = [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

const remAdjDups = (arr, output = []) =>
{
    if (!arr.length)
    {
        console.log("Result before return: ", output);
        return output;
    }

    if (arr[0] === arr[1])
    {
        arr.splice(1, 1);
        remAdjDups(arr, output);
    }
    else
    {
        remAdjDups(arr.slice(1), output.concat(arr[0]));
    }
}

let out = remAdjDups(input.slice());
console.log("output: ", out);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

So, **first and mainly**, I will like to understand what is happening with my approach, and **second** I'm open to any other approach (of any type) that could solve this problem.

---

## Updated Solution

Just in case anyone is interested, I have finally solve this problem using recursion this way. I know filter solution is shorted and elegant, but I was training solving by recursion.

```js
const input = [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

const remAdjDups = ([x, y, ...rest], out = []) =>
{
    if (!rest.length)
        return (x === y) ? [...out, x] : [...out, x, y];
    else if (x === y)
        return remAdjDups([x, ...rest], out);
    else
        return remAdjDups([y, ...rest], [...out, x]);
}

let out = remAdjDups(input.slice());
console.log("output: ", out);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Regarding your solution, just add `return` before `remAdjDups(arr...`

P.S.

I used [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for that

```js
const input = [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

const result = input.filter((i,idx) => input[idx-1] !== i)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Ok, this is nice approach! However, I'm mainly interested on why my approach isn't working.

Comment: @Shidersz I've already updated my answer to answer that as well (before you wrote your comment)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I should delete the question, if wasn't because I already voted on your answers...

Comment: @Shidersz Happens to all of us! Why delete? No one has flagged it as unappropriate or duplicate. Hence you should choose the best answer (probably considering also which one appeared earlier).

Answer (score 3):

Recursion by mathematical induction works nicely for this problem -

1. If the first element, `a`, is null, return the empty result
2. (induction) the first element is NOT null. If the second element, `b`, is null, return a singleton array of the first element, `a`
3. (induction) neither the first element NOR the second element are null. If `a` is equal to `b`, return the recursive result with `a` removed
4. (induction) neither the first element nor the second element are null and they are NOT equal to one another. Return the recursive result without removing either `a` or `b`

```js
const removeDupes = ([ a, b, ...more ]) =>
  a == null
    ? []                                  // 1
: b == null
    ? [ a ]                               // 2
: a === b
    ? removeDupes([ b, ...more ])         // 3
: [ a, ...removeDupes([ b, ...more ]) ]   // 4

const input =
  [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

const result =
  removeDupes(input)
  
console.log(result)
// [ 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const input = [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

const result = input.filter((i,index) => {
 if(index != 0){
  return input[index-1] !== i
 } 
 return i
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, you just forgot to `return` the result from the `recursive` call. All you need is to add `return` statement.

```js
const input = [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

const remAdjDups = (arr, output = []) =>
{
    if (!arr.length)
    {
        console.log("Result before return: ", output);
        return output;
    }

    if (arr[0] === arr[1])
    {
        arr.splice(1, 1);
        return remAdjDups(arr, output);
    }
    else
    {
        return remAdjDups(arr.slice(1), output.concat(arr[0]));
    }
}

let out = remAdjDups(input.slice());
console.log("output: ", out);
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Yo need to use `return` in the `if` and `else` blocks of your code as otherwise `undefined` is going to be returned.

```
if (arr[0] === arr[1])
{
    arr.splice(1, 1);
    return remAdjDups(arr, output);
}
else
{
    return remAdjDups(arr.slice(1), output.concat(arr[0]));
}
```

This is another approach using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const input = [2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 3, 3, 5, 8, 8, 0, -1, -1, 2, 56, 57, 56];

const arr = input.reduce((acc, ele, idx) => {
  if(ele !== input[idx + 1]){
   acc.push(ele)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```